# Historical, versioned and immutable data

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, sql-server-2012, event-sourcing

We need to add data auditing to a project.

We could create some kind of `Log` or `Audit` table to record the changes in our SQL database.  But would it not be a better idea to have the data in the database to be immutable.  So, instead of updating existing values, rather add a new time-stamped row.  This way ALL changes are tracked.

We are using the repository pattern, so this can provide a means to completely abstract this immutability/history/versioning away from client code.  Our repositories consist of the basic CRUD operations (add, update, delete, find/gets).  The following changes would need to occur:

- **Add:**  Insert with a new `Identity` and set the `Timestamp`.
- **Update:** Insert with the old Identity value and set the `Timestamp`.
- **Delete**:  Insert with the old Identity, set the `IsDeleted` flag to true and set the `Timestamp`.
- **Find/Gets:** Only return rows with the latest `Timestamp` values and where `IsDeleted` is false.

Other approaches:

- [Read from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208064/how-to-implement-historical-versioning): Rather use two timestamp values, a start and an end data.
- Instead of a timestamp, rather use some kind of `IsLatest` flag

My only gripe with the above is that, if the data had somehow got bad, multiple rows could be returned for a given date and time.

**Is there any major flaw in this design or is there something I could have done differently?  Is there perhaps a formalized approach the the above?**

Is this somehow related to event sourcing?

Comment: Is this an OLAP or OLTP database?

Comment: Yes, there is a major flaw in your design: you will need to update all foreign keys pointing to the "latest" record each time you change it. Use History Tables or SQL:2011 Temporal Extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My take on this:

You will lose the ability to create unique constraints on the data, except the identity columns.

Also, complicate FK handling. What happens when you update a parent row? It's the insert, thus new identity, but the child rows still reference the "old" record.

Performance will suffer.

I will advise to create a separate table for the archive. You can simplify the updates using the OUTPUT clause with UPDATE, and inserting into archive in same statement.

The approach you're describing is more appropriate for a DWH then an OLTP database.